# Recycle View lagging/ crashing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In test application I am trying to work with RecyclerView and scroll them synchronously. However, during a horizontal scroll I have a problem probable with caching and the application crashes. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the cod:

```
public class TestActivty extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String Tag = TestActivty.class.getName();
int mCurX = 0;
int countMainRecyleView = 0;
int countItemRecyleView = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.v_activty);
    final RecyclerView mainRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    final LinearLayoutManager verticalLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(verticalLinearLayoutManager);
    final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener masterOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        RecyclerView masterRecyclerView = null;
        RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = this;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                    switch (newState) {
                        case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                            if (masterRecyclerView != null) {
                                masterRecyclerView = null;
                                final int firstVisibleItemPosition = verticalLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                                final int lastVisibleItemPosition = verticalLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                                for (int i = firstVisibleItemPosition; i <= lastVisibleItemPosition; ++i) {
                                    RecyclerView horizontalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mainRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView;
                                    if (horizontalRecyclerView != recyclerView)
                                        horizontalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                        case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                            if (masterRecyclerView == null) {
                                masterRecyclerView = recyclerView;
                                final int firstVisibleItemPosition = verticalLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                                final int lastVisibleItemPosition = verticalLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                                for (int i = firstVisibleItemPosition; i <= lastVisibleItemPosition; ++i) {
                                    RecyclerView horizontalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mainRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView;
                                    if (horizontalRecyclerView != recyclerView)
                                        horizontalRecyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
                                }
                            }

                    }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    mCurX += dx;
                     int firstVisibleItemPosition = verticalLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                     int lastVisibleItemPosition = verticalLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    for (int i = firstVisibleItemPosition; i <= lastVisibleItemPosition; ++i) {

                        RecyclerView horizontalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mainRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView;
                        if (horizontalRecyclerView != recyclerView)
                            horizontalRecyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);
                        horizontalRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
                    }

        }
    };

    mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            RecyclerView horizontalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_recycler_view, parent, false);
            horizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TestActivty.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

            horizontalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(masterOnScrollListener);
            final RecyclerView.ViewHolder horizontalViewHolder = new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(horizontalRecyclerView) {
            };
            horizontalRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
                @Override
                public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
                    return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false)) {
                    };
                }

                @Override
                public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
                    ((TextView) holder.itemView).setText("horizontalRecyclerView:" + horizontalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() + "\nitem:" + position);
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemCount() {
                    return 50;
                }
            });
            return horizontalViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) holder.itemView;
            recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(masterOnScrollListener);
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            recyclerView.scrollBy(mCurX,0);
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(masterOnScrollListener);
            recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 105;
        }
    });
}}
```

The main xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the RecycleView item xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Finally, here is the error logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference
at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:80)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(RecyclerView.java:3115)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2917)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecorated(RecyclerView.java:7650)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1448)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1180)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1031)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4061)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

++++++++++++++++

```
D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                         at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12678)
                                                                         at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12668)
                                                                         at android.view.View.invalidateViewProperty(View.java:12788)
                                                                         at android.view.View.offsetLeftAndRight(View.java:12299)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.offsetChildrenHorizontal(RecyclerView.java:3888)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.offsetChildrenHorizontal(RecyclerView.java:7228)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.OrientationHelper$1.offsetChildren(OrientationHelper.java:229)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1189)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1019)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1525)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3954)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1436)
                                                                         at verjnakan.TestActivty$1.onScrolled(TestActivty.java:95)
                                                                      at android.sup..
```

Comment: add error logcat

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: `mainRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()` returns null. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32840927/1083957) answer.

Comment: You see, now it does not crash, but it working the way slower... Is there a way to solve it too ?

Comment: @ArturKarapetyan, now you end up having `StackOverflowError`, which means you have a recursion situation. `verjnakan` :-)  Etqan el verjnakan chi :-)

Comment: @azizbekian, mersi patasxani hamar, bayts ete djvar chi kognes haskanm te vonts kazmakerpem et sinxron scroll@ ? Im mot recursian linuma onScrolled() --> scrollBy() --> onScrolled() --> ... , bayts hents eta vor apahovum sinxronutyun@ scrolli, hamenaindpes im haskanalov.

Comment: I haven't investigated you code extensively, but it seems to me you are initiating scroll event from `onScrollStateChanged()`, which further perform scroll and again `onScrollStateChanged()` will be called, and again scroll would happen, and again `onScrollStateChanged()`... I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but surely that's not the right way to do that.

Comment: Got it, but can You please tell the right way ?