# Change text's color for all cards in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have to do the following thing: when a user clicks a button, I need to change the title's color for all cards in RecyclerView. I've been searching and searching and I couldn't find something to help me, except this method: findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int i). Unfortunately, it returns null ([Android recyclerView findViewHolderForAdapterPosition returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836844/android-recyclerview-findviewholderforadapterposition-returns-null)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a new boolean variable in your adapter, let's call it `changeColor` initialize it to `false` on the adapter constructor and then in your `onClick` action method set it to `true` and call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Finally add the test to the `onBindViewHolder` method of your adapter, something like that:

```
// your onclick method
void onClick() {
 //code..;
 changeColor = true;
 yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 if(changeColor)
     holder.yourItemTitle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, newTitleColor));
 else
     holder.yourItemTitle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, defaultTitleColor));
}
```