# How to get particular item's view of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually I wanna get view of particular item in `RecyclerView` in my `fragment.class`. For this purpose I tried to set a `getter` in my `adapter` class then tried to access it in my `fragment` but I'm unable to access the views .

Code of Adapter Class :

```
private List<ViewHolder> holder_list=new ArrayList<>();
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder_list.add(holder);
   }
public ViewHolder getViewHolder(int position){
    return holder_list.get(position);
}
```

Fragment Code:

```
MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder= msgAdp.getViewHolder(msgAdp.getItemCount()-1);
    //Here holder.mMessageView is a text view
Toast.makeText(ctx,holder.mMessageView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: you can use interface as callback to your fragment. something like https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

Comment: See answer dude.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the easiest method

If you want get ViewHolder of item.

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = rvList.getChildViewHolder(rvList.getChildAt(0));
```

or if you want get View object of item.

```
View view = rvList.getChildAt(0);
```

Use the one you need. You can get view or ViewHolder. You can manipulate them as you need.

**Edit:**

getChildAt method is reliable as i also face issue some time, may be it is not yet fixed.

You can use this code

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder)
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
if (null != holder) {
   holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.xyz).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**Edit 2: Note**

This is known issue that if you call findViewHolderForAdapterPosition just after setting list then you get NullPointerException.

> if notifyDataSetChanged() has been called but the new layout has not
>   been calculated yet, this method will return null since the new
>   positions of views are unknown until the layout is calculated.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840927/6891563)

For solving this you can do like this.

```
recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder)
                recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
                if (null != holder) {
                    holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.xyz).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }, 50);
```

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for your answer but I'm still unable to access the view by your method . I'm getting nullPointerException

Comment: Which method are you using and paste your exception so that i can tell what's wrong with that.

Comment: **View view = rView.getChildAt(0);
        RelativeLayout rl=view.findViewById(R.id.socListContainer);
        rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);** the error is pointed at the *rl* line . Here rl is the container

Comment: If you are getting nullpointer exception then you should check again your view Ids and your list that is that position present. Can you tell me what is being null in your code?

Comment: **holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.xyz).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);** this line is being pointed out as nullpointerexception and by the way ids are correct I've checked them twice

Comment: Welcome dude, its my passion

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I found a solution, which is very simple and short
very simple line code
`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(your position);`