# How do iterate through all the views/items in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I need to iterate through all the `RadioGroups` in my `RecyclerView`.

**Code i tried:**

```
for(int i=0;i<recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();i++)
  {
     radioGroup = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
  }
```

but `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)` returns `null` for RadioGroups that are off screen and gives me a `NullPointerException`.

How do i iterate through all of them?

Comment: Pls share your whole proper code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android recyclerView findViewHolderForAdapterPosition returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836844/android-recyclerview-findviewholderforadapterposition-returns-null)

Comment: @HemantParmar That question did not have a answer that was of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RecyclerView views are created/destroyed as needed when you scroll.  You cannot rely on them being available.

I assume you are trying to retrieve the selection state.  It is better to store this within your object in the adapter and update its value upon clicking a radio button.

Then you can implement a getItem method in your adapter that returns the object and it's current selection state.