# Access all (including invisible) views in Recycler/List View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` with some Views in it, and I need to iterate over *all* of them, not only the visible ones.

I tried to store all the `ViewHolders` after their creation but that didn't work

I also thought of creating all the Views manually and storing them, and then passing them to a `ListView` to display them, but I have no idea how to implement a `ListView` with a complete View list, since this cannot be done with an `Adapter`. (right?)

Is there any solution for this?

**Edit:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947445/how-do-iterate-through-all-the-views-items-in-a-recyclerview) didn't quite solve my problem, as it basically says "The views are recycled", however I was searching for a way to store the views and pass them to the `Adapter` *without them being recycled (=destroyed/recreated)*. By now I figured that a `ScrollView` is the way to go for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do iterate through all the views/items in a RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947445/how-do-iterate-through-all-the-views-items-in-a-recyclerview)

Comment: the `visible ones` are `all of them`. RecyclerView does not have separate views for all the items, it reuses the visible ones.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I do know that, however I don't know how to articulate my problem any better. I know that the views are recycled, I just want a ListView with a list of views I can access any time...

Comment: that won't be `ListView` anymore. It will be just a ScrollView with all the views. Please instead of thea explain why  you want to manipulate all the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Vladyslav Matviienko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1568530/vladyslav-matviienko) sparked the idea that fixed my problem:

I just use a custom `ScrollView` now, which allows me to access all the views anytime.