# Android - Get row from RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I need to get a reference to a specific row within my `recyclerView`.

I used to do it like this

```
View row = recyclerView.childAt(position);
```

since the `childAt()` method is based on the `ViewGroup`, once the list is scrolled, the positions are messed up.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30883242/6427630) I had to use `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()` which returns a `ViewHolder`.

How do I get from the `ViewHolder` to the actual `View` I need to work with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your should  use **[findViewByPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html)**

> `findViewByPosition(int position)`
>
> Finds the view which represents the given adapter position.

```
View row = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(YourPosition);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the view from the ViewHolder using its public `itemView` member variable:

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
final View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
```